# Support on Windows for Sony noise-canceling in-ear earphones

Tags: windows-7, noise-cancelling

I have these  Sony noise-canceling in-ear earphones (model number: mdr-nc31e):

[image]

They came with my Sony Xperia Z2 phone. On the Z2 they kind of work. I can't hear my colleges talking if I plug them in (without even playing music and that's great).

But however if I use them with other devices the noise-canceling does not work. Are there any drivers for example for Windows? Or is this hardware specific?

Comment: A model number might help.

Comment: mdr-nc31e Thats the only thing I can find!

Comment: http://blog.gsmarena.com/sony-mdr-nc31e-noise-cancelling-headset-flash-review/ looks like they only work on that phone and a few other sony models. My guess with be that all the noise cancelling magic is in the phone, rather than in the earbuds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a non-solvable hardware issue. [Sony agrees](http://www.sonymobile.com/global-en/products/accessories/digital-noise-cancelling-headset-mdr-nc31em/).

From what i've seen it's a 5-pin jack. One of the pins is dedicated for noise feedback.
Your PC probably has only 3 pins.

Noise cancellation requires a [digital circuit to measure, process and invert the noise signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise-cancelling_headphones).

According to [this](http://www.phonearena.com/news/The-Sony-Xperia-Z2-comes-with-built-in-active-noise-cancellation.-Here-is-how-it-works_id53736) article: "*sound processing and battery power are provided by the device they are plugged into*". Your PC hasn't got one of those either.

Comment: Ok now I know this is a hardware specific (and not just a driver) issue.

Comment: I'd guess the extra pins (headsets do TRRS) are to feed the pickups in the headphones into the phone for processing. Interesting approach actually, I've heard of DIY designs that do the same thing.